# How to remove an element from a vector using remove_if

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, iterator

I have the below code: I face compilation error in remove function. I want to remove the elements from the vector whose elements have an `x` match the value of input `x`.

```
class A
{
   int x,y;
   public:
   init(int a, int b)
   {
     x = a; y= b;
   }
   int getX(){return x;}
}
class B
{
   public:
   void add (int a, int b)
   {
     A a1;
     a1.init(a,b);
     MyVector.push_back(a1);
   }
   void remove(int x)
   {
      MyVector.erase(remove_if(MyVector.begin(), MyVector.end(),                                         
                  [&vec](int x){return (vec.getX() == x);}), MyVector.end());

   }
   vector<A> MyVector;
}
```

Comment: What's your error?

Comment: classTest.cpp:72:52: note: PointVector::remove(int)::__lambda4
                                        [&vec](int x){return (vec.getX() == x);}), testVector.end());
                                                    ^
classTest.cpp:72:52: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘A’ to ‘int’

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error instead of putting it in a comment.

Answer (score 5):

You must give a return type to `init(int a, int b)` and you've missed two `;`s after the classes definitions and used `std::remove_if()` incorrectly. here is its [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove#:%7E:text=Removes%20all%20elements%20satisfying%20specific,which%20predicate%20p%20returns%20true.)

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
class A
{
    int x,y;
public:
    void init(int a, int b)
    {
        x = a; y= b;
    }
    int getX(){return x;}
};
class B
{
public:
    void add (int a, int b)
    {
        A a1;
        a1.init(a,b);
        MyVector.push_back(a1);
    }
    void remove(int x)
    {
        MyVector.erase(std::remove_if(MyVector.begin(), MyVector.end(),
                                 [&x](auto & el){return (el.getX() == x);}), MyVector.end());

    }
    std::vector<A> MyVector;
};
```

Note that `auto & el == A & el`. `std::remove_if` iterates over the vector and passes its elements to the lambda, hence the lambda argument type should be as the vector's one.

Comment: Just wondering for the parameter in the lambda, what's the difference between using `auto & el` there vs. using `auto el`?

Comment: @Ranoiaetep to pass the elements by reference, not by value to avoid copying.

Comment: testVector.erase(remove_if(testVector.begin(), testVector.end(),
                                        [&x](point& p){return (p.getX() == x);}), testVector.end()); This still gives me error

Comment: can someone explain how to write this part in the code. "[&x](auto & el){return (el.getX() == x);})"

Comment: [x](Point p){return (p.getX() == x);} worked finally